# call different stream builders

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter i have this:
i have `BottomNavigationBar`

```
 body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
        onTap: onTabTapped, // new
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [....


  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {


        _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }


 List<Widget> _children = [....
```

its a `StatefulWidget`

now on each click on a tab i want to call data from `Firestore` but this data might take some time to arrive so `Flutter` gives me an error

> a build function returned null

as  i understand that there is no data coming from firestore but if i put a breakpoint then this will give flutter some time to get the data and its displays(of couse i dont want that ) i want when i click on each tab then to get its data

i tried to put the code in the `onTabTapped` method cause it has `setState` but no luck

Thanks

Code for Streambuilder1

```
 Flexible(
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .document("0ffFhdypVOgfzOXIcTKK")
                  .collection("recomended")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return new Text("Loading");
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        child: new Card(
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 126,
                                child: Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]["Img"],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                              ),
```

Code for Streambuilder 2

i tried putting it in a method and call it

```
Flexible(
  child: tab2,
)
```

tab2=method that calles the second Streambuilder 
   each one is in a different tab

Error i get

```
A build function returned null.
```

the Thing what i want to do is that each tab will display different data and when i click on each tab i want the app to fetch that data

Comment: Add the part of the code where you used the StreamBuilder

Comment: Can you please add the error with the error line

Comment: You don't want the Loading text?